# spring-integratiopn Retry on timeout in a long process gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to retry when my gateway times out, but I can't achieve this.
Apparently the retry advice is wrapping the request, but don't the reply.
Anyway to achieve this in a integration way?

Example Gist: https://gist.github.com/daniel-frank/19dfafbf3d53f4c4b1463107daac540c

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's consider we don't know what is behind that long process. Only what we know that we send request and wait for reply. When we timeout on the service call, there is no guarantee how the server is going to work: maybe it will store reply for the next idempotent call, maybe it just discard everything and forget. Or reply maybe lost on the wire meanwhile we are timeouting...

That's why we fully don't consider the `reply` as independent entity, but just like a part of the whole request-reply action.

Therefore, if we fail during timeout, there is no any other way unless retry the request one more time and try to wait for the reply again. That is already server responsibility to react properly to the same request.

Let me know if you have any valuable thought on the matter!

Comment: I agree with the question of responsibility, but sometimes this 'long process' is beyond the frontier of my integration application.
So we've decided to apply a time out and set up for an exception to be thrown in this case. Additionally, if this happens, make further attempts before finally failing.